# Type error: Argument 2 passed to Controller::show() must be an instance of modal, string given

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Adding up and down voting functions to a classified page. Using Laravel, and Vue.

The error I get is:

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>   Type error: Argument 2 passed to Hustla\Http\Controllers\ListingVoteController::show() must be an instance of Hustla\Listing, string given

I have included the vue file, the vote controller, the listing model, and the route. I was hoping someone could help me out.

**Listing Model**

```
 public function votesAllowed()
 {
     return (bool) $this->allow_votes;
 }

 public function commentsAllowed()
 {
     return (bool) $this->allow_comments;
 }

 public function votes()
 {
  return $this->morphMany(Vote::class, 'voteable');
 }

 public function upVotes()
 {
     return $this->votes()->where('type', 'up');
 }

 public function downVotes()
 {
     return $this->votes()->where('type', 'down');
 }

 public function voteFromUser(User $user)
 {
     return $this->votes()->where('user_id', $user->id);
 }
```

**Vote Controller**

```
  public function show(Request $request, Listing $listing)
  {

    $response = [
        'up' => null,
        'down' => null,
        'can_vote' => $listing->votesAllowed(),
        'user_vote' => null,
    ];

    if ($listing->votesAllowed()) {
        $response['up'] = $listing->upVotes()->count();
        $response['down'] = $listing->downVotes()->count();
    }


    if ($request->user()) {
        $voteFromUser = $listing->voteFromUser($request->user())->first();
        $response['user_vote'] = $voteFromUser ? $voteFromUser->type : null;
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $response
    ], 200);
}
```

**Vote.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="listing__voting">
    <a href="#" class="listing__voting-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    </a> 1 &nbsp;

    <a href="#" class="listing__voting-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
    </a> 2 
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    data () {
        return {
            up: null,
            down: null,
            userVote: null,
            canVote: false
        }
    },
    props:{
        listingId: null
    }
}
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/{location}/{listing}/votes',[
'uses' => '\Hustla\Http\Controllers\ListingVoteController@show'
]);
```

Comment: the Listing $listing part of your show method is expecting an object of type listing. Your route is sending it a string via {listing}. You'll have to fix one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your route definition has two parameters defined: `{location}` and `{listing}`. The parameters are passed to the controller method in the order in which they are defined.

Your controller method, however, is only defined to accept one route parameter. The first route parameter is what will be passed to the method, and in this route definition, that is the `{location}` parameter. Since `{location}` does not match `$listing`, the string value will be passed in, and you'll get the error you're seeing.

You need to add the second route parameter to your controller action:

```
public function show(Request $request, $location, Listing $listing)
{
    // code
}
```

If `$location` is a model as well, you can go ahead and add the type hint to enable the implicit route model binding.